# Swagger definition from model

Tags: node.js, mongoose, yaml, swagger

I have this data model:

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


let ProviderSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  emailTemplate: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "EmailTemplate",
    required: false
  }
});


let ProductsSchema = new Schema({
    brand: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Brand",
        required: true 
    },
    providers: {
        type: [ProviderSchema],
        required: false
    }
});


let ListSchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  products: {
    type: [ProductsSchema],
    default: [],
    required: true
  }
}, { collection: 'list' });


module.exports = mongoose.model("List", ListSchema);
```

But when I try to build the swagger definition I have problems. How can I define the "products" property of my model?
I tried to do it with type array but it gives me an error in the swagger validation, I think because it is badly built. I'm new to swagger and it's complicated to define this

Here is my .yaml

```
required:
  - code
properties:
  code:
    type: string
  products:
    type: array
        items:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Brand'
```

Comment: Do you write the YAML manually or generate it from code?

Comment: I've written it manually, I do not know how it can be generated from code, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is important in YAML. Make sure `items` is on the same level as `type: array`.

```yaml
required:
  - code
properties:
  code:
    type: string
  products:
    type: array
    items:      # <-------
      $ref: '#/definitions/Brand'
```